# How to change the behavior of cancelbutton in the NSSearchField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

In Finder , i find that the cancel button disappear when the NSSearchfield get focus first time,but when i input something to the searchfield,the cancel button is there all the time unless i click it.I also create a nssearchfield manully and input some words.However,when I delete the word one by one until nothing,at last,the cancel button disappear.It looks like the default behavior of the nssearchfield,so how can i change the default behavior?
please help,thank you!

Comment: You'll have to subclass it.

Comment: do u have some sample code?

Comment: thank u ,i will search it

Comment: I set the searchfield's delegate and the function that is controlTextDidChange:.I want to make the cancelbutton show when the searchfield has nothing.but i find the cancel button is actually NSButtonCell and it has not the function of setHidden.So the problem is still exited！

Answer (score 5):

You can access the cancel button directly:

#### Swift

```Swift
let searchField = NSSearchField()

// Change the button:
if let cell = searchField.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell,
    let cancelButton = cell.cancelButtonCell {
    // Here you can access all properties of a NSButtonCell
}

// Hide the button:
searchField.cell?.cancelButtonCell = nil
```

#### Objective C

```objc
NSSearchField* searchField = [NSSearchField new]

// Change the button:
NSSearchFieldCell* cell = searchField.cell
NSButtonCell* cancelButton = cell.cancelButtonCell
if (cancelButton) {
    // Here you can access all properties of a NSButtonCell
}

// Hide the button:
searchField.cell.cancelButtonCell = nil
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer.

Comment: @gohamgx You're welcome! If this answered your question, be sure to click the checkmark to the left.